# Deriving $\Lambda^i_{\,j}$ components of the Lorentz transformation matrix

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, inertial-frames

I am trying to follow Weinberg's derivation (in the book Gravitation and Cosmology) of the Lorentz transformation or boost along arbitrary direction. I am having trouble deriving the $\Lambda^i_{\,j}$ components. Here's how I am trying,
\begin{align}
    \eta_{0i}=0&=\eta_{\alpha\beta}\Lambda^\alpha_{\,0}\Lambda^\beta_{\,i}\nonumber\\
    &=\eta_{00}\Lambda^0_{\,0}\Lambda^0_{\,i}+\eta_{jk}\Lambda^j_{\,0}\Lambda^k_{\,i}\nonumber\\
    &=-c^2\gamma\left(-\frac{1}{c^2}\gamma v_i\right)+\eta_{jk}\left(-v^j\gamma\right)\Lambda^k_{\,i}\nonumber\\
    &=\gamma^2 v_i-\gamma v_k\Lambda^k_{\,i}
\end{align}
Then we have,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
    v_k\Lambda^k_{\,i}=\gamma v_i
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
How do I go from the above equation to the solution below?
$$\Lambda^i_{\,j}=\delta^i_{\,j}+\frac{v^i v_j}{\mathbf{v}^2}\left(\gamma-1\right)$$
I am a newbie in the subject and please show the in between steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to see a general quick derivation that follows on exactly in the spirit of Weinberg.

Recall this involves considering a particle in a frame $\mathcal{O}$ in which the particle appears to have no velocity and also in a frame $\mathcal{O}'$ in which it appears to have velocity
$$
\mathbf{v} = (\frac{dx'^i}{dt'}),$$
and then using
$$dt' = \Lambda^0_{\,\,\,0} dt,$$
$$dx'^i = \Lambda^i_{\,\,\,0} dt,$$
along with the $00$ component of the identity
$$\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\gamma} \Lambda^{\beta}_{\,\,\,\delta} \eta_{\alpha \beta} = \eta_{\gamma \delta}$$
to show that a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\beta}$ between these frames must satisfy
$$\Lambda^0_{\,\,\,0} = \gamma$$
$$\Lambda^i_{\,\,\,0} = \gamma v^i,$$
while the remaining $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\beta}$ components are not uniquely fixed as above since for any rotation $R^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\beta}$ we have that both $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\beta}$  and $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\gamma} R^{\gamma}_{\,\,\,\beta}$ will transform from the frame where the particle appears with zero velocity to the frame where it appears to have velocity $\mathbf{v}$.

One way, which is similar to [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-derive-the-Lorentz-transformation-of-a-general-boost), is to first consider the special case (boo) of a frame in which $v^1 = v, v^2 = 0, v^3 = 0$ and then try to write the results so that it easily applies for any $\mathbf{v}$. Thus, given
$$
\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\beta} = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & \gamma v & 0 & 0 \\ \gamma v & \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,3} \\ 0 & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,3} \\ 0 & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,3} \end{bmatrix} $$
use the fact that
\begin{align}
1 &= \det(\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\beta} ) \\
&= \gamma \begin{bmatrix}  \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,3} \\ \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,3} \\ \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,3} \end{bmatrix} - \gamma v \begin{bmatrix} \gamma v & 0 & 0 \\  \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,3} \\ \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,3} \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \gamma \begin{bmatrix}  \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,3} \\ \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,3} \\ \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,1} & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,3} \end{bmatrix} - \gamma^2 v^2 \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^2_{\,\,\,3} \\ \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,2} & \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,3} \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
to motivate choosing the rotation $R^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\beta}$ so that the obvious relations
$$\Lambda^1_{\,\,\,1} = \gamma$$
$$\Lambda^2_{\,\,\,2} = \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,3} = 1$$
$$\Lambda^1_{\,\,\,2} = \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,3} = ... = 0$$
make the above determinant relation an identity. Thus we work with
$$
\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\,\,\,\beta} = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & \gamma v & 0 & 0 \\ \gamma v & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
Now, since the $3 \times 3$ spatial part of the matrix should reduce to $I$ when $\mathbf{v} = (v,0,0)$ is zero, we simply try to re-write it as in terms of the identity and a part that depends on $\mathbf{v}$ in a way that will easily generalize to arbitrary $\mathbf{v}$'s via
\begin{align}
\Lambda^{i}_{\,\,\,j} &= \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= I + (\begin{bmatrix} \gamma & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} - I) \\
&= I +  \begin{bmatrix} \gamma - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= I +  (\gamma - 1) \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \\
&= I +  (\gamma - 1) (1,0,0) \otimes (1,0,0)^T \\
&= I +  (\gamma - 1) \frac{1}{v^2} v(1,0,0) \otimes v (1,0,0)^T \\
&= I +  (\gamma - 1) \frac{1}{\mathbf{v}^2} \mathbf{v} \otimes \mathbf{v}^T \\
&= \delta^i_{\,\,\,j} + (\gamma - 1) \frac{1}{\mathbf{v}^2} v^i v_j
\end{align}
This is Weinberg's (2.1.20), where I still have $\mathbf{v} = (v,0,0)$, but now the relation is a vector relation independent of the form of $\mathbf{v}$ so you can just set $\mathbf{v} = (v^1,v^2,v^3)$.

The choice $\mathbf{v} = (v,0,0)$ means  $\Lambda^i_{\,\,\,0} = \gamma v^i$ reduces down to $\Lambda^i_{\,\,\,0} = \gamma v^i = (\gamma v,0,0)$ but it is easily generalized to a general $\mathbf{v}$ frame again by setting $\Lambda^i_{\,\,\,0} = \gamma v^i$ for general $\mathbf{v}$, which is (2.1.21).

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted the answer. But I've only one remaining doubt. As you write "to motivate choosing the rotation $R^\alpha_{\,\,\beta}$ so that the obvious relations..." Do you mean I can choose a rotation matrix such that any general matrix $\Lambda^i_{\,\,j}$ becomes, $$\Lambda^1_{\,\,\,1} = \gamma$$
$$\Lambda^2_{\,\,\,2} = \Lambda^3_{\,\,\,3} = 1$$
$$\Lambda^1_{\,\,\,2} = \Lambda^1_{\,\,\,3} = ... = 0$$

Comment: Yes. I've found a few sets of notes which cite Weinberg such as [this](https://people.physics.tamu.edu/pope/GravPhys2019/grav-phys.pdf) (see equations 2.3 and 2.18) and [this](https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/2012-09-20/ht17_pdf_14166.pdf) (see equations 10 and 56) and you see they always refer to the formula I derived above (they just state it or ask you to prove it) as a way to motivate it's general form so while still hopeful I'm doubtful one can do much better than this.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two inertial systems $Oy_1y_2y_3t$ and  $O'y'_1y'_2y'_3t'$ with common axis $\left(y'_1,y_1\right)$ and parallel axes the pairs $\left(y'_2,y_2\right),\left(y'_3,y_3\right)$. If the primed system $O'y'_1y'_2y'_3$ is moving with uniform velocity $\mathbf v_0=v\,\mathbf e_1$ along the common axis with respect to the system $Oy_1y_2y_3$ then the $1+1-$ Lorentz transformation is
\begin{align}
y'_1 & = \gamma\left(y_1-v\,t\right)
\tag{01a}\label{01a}\\
y'_2 & = y_2
\tag{01b}\label{01b}\\
y'_3 & = y_3
\tag{01c}\label{01c}\\
t' & = \gamma\left(t-\dfrac{v}{c^2}\,y_1\right)
\tag{01d}\label{01d}\\
\gamma & = \left(1-\frac{\upsilon^2}{c^{2}}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} 
\tag{01e}\label{01e}
\end{align}
This boost along the $y_1-$axis  is in matrix form
\begin{equation}
\mathbf Y'=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\mathbf y'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
c\,t'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
y'_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
y'_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
y'_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
y'_4\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \hphantom{-}\gamma & \:\:0\:\: & \:\:0\:\: & -\dfrac{\gamma v}{c}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
 \hphantom{-}0 & \:\:1\:\: & \:\:0\:\: & \hphantom{-} 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
 \hphantom{-}0 & \:\:0\:\: & \:\:1\:\: & \hphantom{-} 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
-\dfrac{\gamma v}{c} & \:\:0\:\: & \:\:0\:\: & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
y_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
y_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
y_4\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
=\mathcal B\,\mathbf Y
\tag{02}\label{02}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\mathcal B=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
   \hphantom{-}\gamma & \:\:0\:\: & \:\:0\:\: & -\dfrac{\gamma v}{c}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
   \hphantom{-}0 & \:\:1\:\: & \:\:0\:\: & \hphantom{-} 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
   \hphantom{-}0 & \:\:0\:\: & \:\:1\:\: & \hphantom{-} 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
   -\dfrac{\gamma v}{c} & \:\:0\:\: & \:\:0\:\: & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm B\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v_{0}}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
    & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v_{0}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}{c} &  & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{03}\label{03}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\rm B=
\begin{bmatrix}
   \:\gamma & \:\:0\:\: & \:0\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
   \:0 & \:\: 1\:\: & \:0 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
   \:0 & \:\: 0\:\: & \:1 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
\,,\qquad
\mathbf v_{0}=
\begin{bmatrix}
   \:v \:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
   \:0 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
   \:0 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:
\end{bmatrix}
\,,\qquad
\mathbf v_{0}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
   \:v \: & \:0 \:& \:0 \:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{04}\label{04}
\end{equation}

In order to make the boost more general, that is not restricted to velocities parallel to the common axis $\left(y'_1,y_1\right)$, we make in the system $\:Oy_1y_2y_3\:$ a rotation $\;\rm R\;$ of the spatial coordinate system to map $\:(y_1,y_2,y_3) \equiv \mathbf y\: \longrightarrow\: (x_1,x_2,x_3)\equiv\mathbf x \:$ such that the velocity
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf v_{0}=(v,0,0)=v\,\mathbf e_1
\tag{05}\label{05}
\end{equation}
of system $\:O'y'_1y'_2y'_3\:$ relatively to  $\:Oy_1y_2y_3\:$ to be transformed to
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{v}=(\upsilon_1,\upsilon_2,\upsilon_3)
\tag{06}\label{06}
\end{equation}
To keep the spatial coordinate system right orthonormal we choose any real orthogonal matrix $\;\rm R\;$ with positive unit determinant :
\begin{equation}
\mathrm R =
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\,,\qquad
\mathrm R^{-1} =\mathrm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{11} & R_{21} & R_{31} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{12} & R_{22} & R_{32} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{13} & R_{23} & R_{33} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{07}\label{07} 
\end{equation}
So we must have
\begin{equation}
\rm R\mathbf{v}_{0}=\mathbf{v}
\tag{08}\label{08}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \:v \:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
   \:0 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
   \:0 \: \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\:
\end{bmatrix}
  =
\begin{bmatrix}
   \:v_1 \:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
   \:v_2 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
   \:v_3 \: \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\:
\end{bmatrix}   
\tag{09}\label{09}
\end{equation}
hence
\begin{equation}
R_{11}=\dfrac{v_1}{v}\,,\qquad R_{21}=\dfrac{v_2}{v}\,,\qquad R_{31}=\dfrac{v_3}{v}
\tag{10.1}\label{10.1}
\end{equation}
Note that due to the property $\:\rm R\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}=\rm I\:$ the three rows of $\:\rm R\:$ constitute an orthonormal system, so on one hand they are unit 3-vectors
\begin{align}
R^2_{11}+R^2_{12}+R^2_{13} & =1 \implies R^2_{12}+R^2_{13}  =1-R^2_{11}=1-\dfrac{v^2_1}{v^2}
\tag{10.2}\label{10.2}\\
R^2_{21}+R^2_{22}+R^2_{23} & =1 \implies R^2_{22}+R^2_{23}  =1-R^2_{21}=1-\dfrac{v^2_2}{v^2}
\tag{10.3}\label{10.3}\\
R^2_{31}+R^2_{32}+R^2_{33} & =1 \implies R^2_{32}+R^2_{33}  =1-R^2_{31}=1-\dfrac{v^2_3}{v^2}
\tag{10.4}\label{10.4}
\end{align}
and on the other hand they are normal to each other

<sup>\begin{align}
R_{11}R_{21}+R_{12}R_{22}+R_{13}R_{23} & =0 \implies R_{12}R_{22}+R_{13}R_{23} =-R_{11}R_{21}=-\dfrac{v_1v_2}{v^2}
\tag{10.5}\label{10.5}\\
R_{11}R_{31}+R_{12}R_{32}+R_{13}R_{33} & =0 \implies R_{12}R_{32}+R_{13}R_{33} =-R_{11}R_{31}=-\dfrac{v_1v_3}{v^2}
\tag{10.6}\label{10.6}\\
R_{21}R_{31}+R_{22}R_{32}+R_{23}R_{33} & =0 \implies R_{22}R_{32}+R_{23}R_{33} =-R_{21}R_{31}=-\dfrac{v_2v_3}{v^2}
\tag{10.7}\label{10.7}
\end{align}</sup>

relations useful for what it follows.

In the $3+1-$dimensional Minkowski space the rotation $\rm R$ is represented by the following $4\times 4-$matrix

<sup>\begin{equation}
\mathcal R=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm R\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}\boldsymbol 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
    & \hphantom{--} \boldsymbol 0^{\boldsymbol{\top}} &  & \hphantom{-} 1 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\,,\qquad 
\mathcal R^{-1}=\mathcal R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}\boldsymbol 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
    & \hphantom{-}\: \boldsymbol 0^{\boldsymbol{\top}} &  & \hphantom{-} 1 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{11}\label{11} 
\end{equation}</sup>

where
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol 0=
\begin{bmatrix}
   \:0 \:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
   \:0 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\\ 
   \:0 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:
\end{bmatrix}
\,,\qquad
\boldsymbol 0^{\boldsymbol{\top}}=
\begin{bmatrix}
   \:0 \: & \:0 \:& \:0 \:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{12}\label{12}
\end{equation}
hence
\begin{equation}
\mathbf X =
\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\mathbf x\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
c\,t\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
x_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
x_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
x_4\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{=}\rm R\hphantom{^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}  & \hphantom{====}\boldsymbol 0\hphantom{=} \vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma}{c}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\hphantom{=}\boldsymbol 0^{\boldsymbol{\top}} & \hphantom{====}1\hphantom{=} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
y_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
y_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
y_4\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
=\mathcal R\,\mathbf Y
\tag{13}\label{13}
\end{equation}
Now, if in the primed system  $O'y'_1y'_2y'_3$ exactly the same rotation $\rm R$ is used to map $\:(y'_1,y'_2,y'_3) \equiv \mathbf y'\:\longrightarrow\: (x'_1,x'_2,x'_3)\equiv\mathbf x' \:$ then
\begin{equation}
\mathbf X' =
\begin{bmatrix}
\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\mathbf x'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
c\,t'\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
x'_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
x'_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
x'_4\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{=}\rm R\hphantom{^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}  & \hphantom{====}\boldsymbol 0\hphantom{=} \vphantom{\dfrac{\gamma}{c}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}\vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\hphantom{=}\boldsymbol 0^{\boldsymbol{\top}} & \hphantom{====}1\hphantom{=} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y'_1\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
y'_2\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
y'_3\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\
y'_4\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
=\mathcal R\,\mathbf Y'
\tag{14}\label{14}
\end{equation}
The transformation matrix $\:\rm L\left(\mathbf v\right)$ <sup>(1)</sup> for the Lorentz boost with velocity $\:\mathbf v\:$ of arbitrary direction is that connecting the 4-vectors $\:\mathbf X\:$ and  $\:\mathbf X'$
\begin{equation}
\mathbf X' = \mathcal R\,\mathbf Y'=\mathcal R\,\mathcal B\,\mathbf Y=\mathcal R\,\mathcal B\,\mathcal R^{-1}\,\mathbf X=\mathcal R\,\mathcal B\,\mathcal R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\,\mathbf X
\tag{15}\label{15}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf X' = \rm L\left(\mathbf v\right)\mathbf X 
\tag{16}\label{16}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\rm L\left(\mathbf v\right) = \mathcal R\,\mathcal B\,\mathcal R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}
\tag{17}\label{17}
\end{equation}
So

<sup>\begin{align}
\rm L\left(\mathbf v\right) & = 
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm R\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}\boldsymbol 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
    & \hphantom{--} \boldsymbol 0^{\boldsymbol{\top}} &  & \hphantom{-} 1 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm B\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v_{0}}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
    & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v_{0}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}{c} &  & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}\boldsymbol 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
    & \hphantom{-}\: \boldsymbol 0^{\boldsymbol{\top}} &  & \hphantom{-} 1 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& =\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm R\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}\boldsymbol 0 \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
    & \hphantom{--} \boldsymbol 0^{\boldsymbol{\top}} &  & \hphantom{-} 1 \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm B\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v_{0}}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
    & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v_{0}^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}{c} &  & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm R\rm B\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \left(\rm R\mathbf v_{0}\right)}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}  \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline
    & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \left(\rm R\mathbf v_{0}\right)^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}{c} &  & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm R\rm B\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}} \:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & -\;\dfrac{\gamma\mathbf v}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline 
    & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}{c} &  & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{18}\label{18}
\end{align}</sup>

that is

<sup>\begin{equation}
\rm L\left(\mathbf v\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm R\rm B\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}} \:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & -\;\dfrac{\gamma\mathbf v}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline 
    & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}{c} &  & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:L_{11}  & \:\:L_{12}\:\:\: & \:\: L_{13}\:\:\:  & L_{14} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:L_{21}  & \:\:L_{22}\:\:\: & \:\: L_{23}\:\:\:  & L_{24} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:L_{31}  & \:\:L_{32}\:\:\: & \:\: L_{33}\:\:\:  & L_{34} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
   \hline 
   \:\:L_{41}  & \:\:L_{42}\:\:\: & \:\: L_{43}\:\:\:  & L_{44} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{19}\label{19}
\end{equation}</sup>

Now
\begin{align}
\rm R\rm B\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}} & = \begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & L_{12} & L_{13} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
L_{21} & L_{22} & L_{23} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
L_{31} & L_{32} & L_{33} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
   \:\gamma & \:\:0\:\: & \:0\:\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
   \:0 & \:\: 1\:\: & \:0 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
   \:0 & \:\: 0\:\: & \:1 \: \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{11} & R_{21} & R_{31} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{12} & R_{22} & R_{32} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{13} & R_{23} & R_{33} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\nonumber\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma R_{11} & \gamma R_{21} & \gamma R_{31} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{12} & R_{22} & R_{32} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\\ 
R_{13} & R_{23} & R_{33} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{20}\label{20} 
\end{align}
Since the matrix $\:\rm R\rm B\rm R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\:$ is symmetric it's sufficient to determine 6 of its elements $\:L_{ij}$

<sup>\begin{align}
L_{11} & = \gamma R^2_{11}+\overbrace{R^2_{12}+R^2_{13}}^{\eqref{10.2} =1-R^2_{11}}=1+\left(\gamma-1\right) R^2_{11}\stackrel{\eqref{10.1}}{=\!=\!=}1+\left(\gamma-1\right)\dfrac{v^2_1}{v^2}=1+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}v^2_1
\tag{21.1}\label{21.1}\\ 
L_{22} & = \gamma R^2_{21}+\overbrace{R^2_{22}+R^2_{23}}^{\eqref{10.3} =1-R^2_{21}}=1+\left(\gamma-1\right) R^2_{21}\stackrel{\eqref{10.1}}{=\!=\!=}1+\left(\gamma-1\right)\dfrac{v^2_2}{v^2}=1+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}v^2_2
\tag{21.2}\label{21.2}\\
L_{33} & = \gamma R^2_{31}+\overbrace{R^2_{32}+R^2_{33}}^{\eqref{10.4} =1-R^2_{31}}=1+\left(\gamma-1\right) R^2_{31}\stackrel{\eqref{10.1}}{=\!=\!=}1+\left(\gamma-1\right)\dfrac{v^2_3}{v^2}=1+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}v^2_3
\tag{21.3}\label{21.3}\\
L_{12} & = \gamma R_{11}R_{21}+\overbrace{R_{12}R_{22}+R_{13}R_{23}}^{\eqref{10.5}=-R_{11}R_{21}}=\left(\gamma-1\right) R_{11}R_{21}\stackrel{\eqref{10.1}}{=\!=\!=}\left(\gamma-1\right)\dfrac{v_1v_2}{v^2}=\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}v_1v_2
\tag{21.4}\label{21.4}\\
L_{13} & = \gamma R_{11}R_{31}+\overbrace{R_{12}R_{32}+R_{13}R_{33}}^{\eqref{10.6}=-R_{11}R_{31}}=\left(\gamma-1\right) R_{11}R_{31}\stackrel{\eqref{10.1}}{=\!=\!=}\left(\gamma-1\right)\dfrac{v_1v_3}{v^2}=\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}v_1v_3
\tag{21.5}\label{21.5}\\
L_{23} & = \gamma R_{21}R_{31}+\overbrace{R_{22}R_{32}+R_{23}R_{33}}^{\eqref{10.7}=-R_{21}R_{31}}=\left(\gamma-1\right) R_{21}R_{31}\stackrel{\eqref{10.1}}{=\!=\!=}\left(\gamma-1\right)\dfrac{v_2v_3}{v^2}=\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}v_2v_3
\tag{21.6}\label{21.6}\\
L_{21} & = L_{12}\,,\qquad  L_{31}=L_{13}\,,\qquad  L_{32}=L_{23}
\tag{21.7}\label{21.7}
\end{align}</sup>

The list of elements  $\:L_{ij}\:$  of the symmetric matrix $\:\rm L\left(\mathbf v\right) = \mathcal R\,\mathcal B\,\mathcal R^{\boldsymbol{\top}}\:$ is completed with that of the fourth row, identical with those of the fourth column
\begin{equation}
L_{41}=L_{14}=-\dfrac{\gamma v_1}{v}\,,\quad  L_{42}=L_{24}=-\dfrac{\gamma v_2}{v}\,,\quad L_{43}=L_{34}=-\dfrac{\gamma v_3}{v}\,,\quad L_{44}=\gamma
\tag{21.8}\label{21.8}
\end{equation}
So finally

<sup>\begin{equation}
\rm L\left(\mathbf v\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm I+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}\mathbf v\mathbf v^{\boldsymbol{\top}} \:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & -\;\dfrac{\gamma\mathbf v}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline 
    & -\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}{c} &  & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:L_{11}  & \:\:L_{12}\:\:\: & \:\: L_{13}\:\:\:  & L_{14} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:L_{21}  & \:\:L_{22}\:\:\: & \:\: L_{23}\:\:\:  & L_{24} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:L_{31}  & \:\:L_{32}\:\:\: & \:\: L_{33}\:\:\:  & L_{34} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
   \hline 
   \:\:L_{41}  & \:\:L_{42}\:\:\: & \:\: L_{43}\:\:\:  & L_{44} \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{22}\label{22}
\end{equation}</sup>

By above equation the Lorentz boost transformation \eqref{16} is expressed explicitly as follows
\begin{align}
\mathbf x' & = \mathbf x+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}\left(\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf x\right)\mathbf v-\gamma\,\mathbf v\,t
\tag{23a}\label{23a}\\
t' & = \gamma\biggl(t-\dfrac{\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf x}{c^2}\biggr)
\tag{23b}\label{23b}\\
\gamma & = \left(1-\frac{\upsilon^2}{c^{2}}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} 
\tag{23c}\label{23c}
\end{align}
and in differential form
\begin{align}
\mathrm d\mathbf x' & = \mathrm d\mathbf  x+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}\left(\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm d\mathbf x\right)\mathbf v-\gamma\,\mathbf v\,\mathrm dt
\tag{24a}\label{24a}\\
\mathrm d t' & = \gamma\biggl(\mathrm d t-\dfrac{\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm d \mathbf x}{c^2}\biggr)
\tag{24b}\label{24b}
\end{align}
It's worth to mention at this point that from this differential form we could find the relativistic sum of two velocity 3-vectors not necessarily  collinear. Dividing \eqref{24a},\eqref{24b} side by side we have
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf x'}{\mathrm d t'} = \dfrac{\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf x}{\mathrm d t}+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}\left(\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\cdot}\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf x}{\mathrm d t}\right)\mathbf v-\gamma\,\mathbf v}{\gamma\left(
\begin{matrix}
1-\dfrac{\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\cdot}\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf x}{\mathrm d t}}{c^2} \\
 \hphantom{-}
\end{matrix}\right)} 
\tag{25}\label{25}
\end{equation}
Replacing
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf x'}{\mathrm d t'} & = \mathbf w'\!=\texttt{particle velocity with respect to }O'x'_1x'_2x'_3
\tag{26a}\label{26a}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf x}{\mathrm d t} & = \mathbf w=\texttt{particle velocity with respect  to }\:Ox_1x_2x_3
\tag{26b}\label{26b}
\end{align}
we have
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf w' = \dfrac{ \mathbf w+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}\left(\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf w\right)\mathbf v-\gamma\,\mathbf v}{\gamma\biggl(1-\dfrac{\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf w}{c^2}\biggr)} 
\tag{27}\label{27}
\end{equation}
the relativistic sum of $\:\mathbf w\:$ and $\boldsymbol{-}\mathbf v$.

Note that for the inverse of the Lorentz boost matrix we have from \eqref{22}
\begin{equation}
\rm L^{-1}=\rm L\left(-\mathbf v\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \:\:  & \:\:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\:  & \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\:  & \:\:\hphantom{-}\rm I+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2\left(\gamma+1\right)}\mathbf v\mathbf v^{\boldsymbol{\top}} \:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & +\;\dfrac{\gamma\mathbf v}{c} \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\ 
  \:\: & \:\:\:\: & \:\:\:\:\: & \hphantom{-}   \vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
   \hline 
    & +\;\dfrac{\gamma \mathbf v^{\boldsymbol{\top}}}{c} &  & \hphantom{-} \gamma \vphantom{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{b}}\:\:
 \end{array} 
\end{bmatrix} 
\tag{28}\label{28}
\end{equation}

---

<sup>(1)
I keep the symbol $\rm L(\mathbf v)$ for Lorentz boosts and $\Lambda$ for the proper homogeneous Lorentz transformations</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As Weinberg says there in that section (page 29), only $\Lambda^0_{\ 0} = 1$ and $\Lambda^{i}_{\ 0} = \gamma v_i$ are uniquely determined - the other $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\ \beta}$ are not uniquely determined (the reason for this being that if $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\ \beta}$ carries a particle from rest to velocity $\mathbf{v}$, then so does $\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\ \delta} R^{\delta}_{\ \beta}$ where $R$ is an arbitrary rotation).

The convenient choice that Weinberg write down is
$$
\Lambda^{i}_{\ j} \ = \ \delta_{ij} + \frac{ v_{i} v_{j} }{ v^2 } (\gamma - 1)
$$
is just a choice.

EDIT: To see that this choice is consistent with your equation, you can write the above as a $3 \times 3$ matrix:
$$
\tilde{\Lambda} = \mathbb{I} + \frac{\gamma - 1}{v^2} \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^{T} 
$$
where $\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^{T}$ is an outer product, and you can verify that the components of this matrix agree with the above. Notice that $v_{k} \Lambda^{k}_{\ j} = \gamma v_{j}$ can be written as $\mathbf{v}^{T} \tilde{\Lambda} = \gamma \mathbf{v}^{T}$ or because $\Lambda$ is symmetric, you can also write this as
$$
\tilde{\Lambda} \mathbf{v} = \gamma \mathbf{v} \ .
$$
Plug in the above matrix to the LHS and you get:
$$
\text{LHS} = \left( \mathbb{I} + \tfrac{\gamma - 1}{v^2} \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^{T} \right) \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v} + \tfrac{\gamma - 1}{v^2} \mathbf{v} \mathbf{v}^{T} \mathbf{v} = \gamma \mathbf{v}
$$
which is $=$RHS, where the last equality uses $\mathbf{v}^{T}\mathbf{v} = v^2$.

EDIT 2: I am wondering if Weinberg has a typo, where he says that $\tilde{\Lambda} R$ also satisfies the equation. I think it should rather be $\tilde{\Lambda}' = R^{T} \tilde{\Lambda} R$, which solves the equation $\tilde{\Lambda}' \mathbf{v} = \gamma \mathbf{v}$ whenever $\tilde{\Lambda}$ does.

Comment: Then please at least show, how this choice is consistent. For example, for $i=j$, I see that the choice is consistent. However, when $i\neq j$, I don't see how to show that the choice is consistent.

Comment: Moreover, if $\Lambda^\alpha_{\,\,\beta}$ carries a particles from rest to $\mathbf{v}$, then shouldn't the transformation $\Lambda^\alpha_{\,\,\gamma}R^\gamma_{\,\,\beta}$ carry the particle from rest to a velocity different in direction than $\mathbf{v}$? I am confused. Can you demonstrate this mathematically without making qualitative/cryptic statements as Weinberg does. As I mentioned, I am a newbie!

Comment: I've written out how Weinberg's choice is consistent. For your other question, it's not that the velocity is physically rotated, it's that your coordinate system you use to describe the $\mathbf{v}$ gets rotated (the particle always moves with the same velocity no matter what's the orientation of your coordinate system)

Comment: Question regarding Edit 3: "$\bar{\Lambda}^\prime=R^T\bar{\Lambda}R$ solves equation $\bar{\Lambda}^\prime\mathbf{v}=\gamma\mathbf{v}$ whenever $\bar{\Lambda}$ does". But I find this, $$\bar{\Lambda}\mathbf{v}=\gamma\mathbf{v}\implies R^T\bar{\Lambda}RR^T\mathbf{v}=\gamma R^T\mathbf{v}\implies \bar{\Lambda}^\prime\mathbf{v^\prime}=\gamma \mathbf{v^\prime},$$ with $\mathbf{v^\prime}=R^T\mathbf{v}$. Therefore, this equation is different from $\bar{\Lambda}^\prime\mathbf{v}=\gamma\mathbf{v}$. Please, elaborate this discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

The components $\Lambda^i_{\,\,\,j}$ cannot be uniquely determined. The best way you can motivate the form of these components are given in [bolbteppa's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/588913/73780). Perhaps this is the best you can do. However, this can still feel like cheating, especially when you generalize the results from $(v,0,0)$ to the case of $\mathbf{v}$. So, this answer will complement the previously cited answer in this generalizing. As we now know our convenient form the components $\Lambda^i_{\,\,\,j}$, we can do the following algebra,

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
    v_k\Lambda^k_{\,\,\,i}=\gamma v_i\\
    v_k\Lambda^k_{\,\,\,i}=\left(\gamma-1 \right)v_i+v_k\delta^k_{\,\,\,\,i}\\
    v_k\Lambda^k_{\,\,\,i}=\left(\gamma-1 \right)v_i\frac{v_kv^k}{\mathbf{v}^2}+v_k\delta^k_{\,\,\,\,i}\\
    v_k\Lambda^k_{\,\,\,i}=v_k\left[\left(\gamma-1 \right)\frac{v_iv^k}{\mathbf{v}^2}+\delta^k_{\,\,\,\,i}\right]\\
    v_k\left[\Lambda^k_{\,\,\,i}-\left(\gamma-1 \right)\frac{v_iv^k}{\mathbf{v}^2}+\delta^k_{\,\,\,\,i}\right]=0
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
Now, as $v^k$ is arbitrary, we must have,
\begin{align}
    \Lambda^k_{\,\,\,i}=\left(\gamma-1 \right)\frac{v_iv^k}{\mathbf{v}^2}+\delta^k_{\,\,\,\,i}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
    \text{Assume }{\Lambda^k}_i = \delta^k _i +c^k _i   
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
    v_k\Lambda^k_{\,\,\,i}=\gamma v_i
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
    v_k\Lambda^k_{\,\,\,i}-\gamma v_i =0
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
    v^i v_k\Lambda^k_{\,\,\,i}-\gamma v^i v_i =0
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
    v^i v_k(\delta^k _i + c^k _i) -\gamma v^2 =0
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
    (v^2 + v^i v_k c^k _i) -\gamma v^2 =0
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
      v^i v_k c^k _i =\gamma v^2 -v^2 =v^2 (\gamma -1)
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
     v_i v^i v_k c^k _i = v_i v^2 (\gamma -1)
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
      v_k c^k _i = v_i  (\gamma -1)
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
      v^k v_k c^k _i = v^k v_i  (\gamma -1)
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
       c^k _i = \frac{v^k v_i}{v^2}  (\gamma -1)
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

Answer (score -3):

This is just a  formula for a boost. The most general Lorentz transformation includes combined boosts and rotations.

I assume that you know the usual formula
$$
\left[\matrix{ t'\cr x'}\right]= \left[\matrix{ \cosh s&-\sinh s\cr-\sinh s &\cosh s}\right]\left[\matrix{ t\cr x}\right]=
$$
where $s$ is the rapidity  with $|{\bf v}|=\tanh s$,and  $\gamma=\cosh s$, etc.

I don't have a copy of Weinberg to hand, but if you want a formula similar to yours for a boost  ${\bf v}$  that  preserves
$t^2-{\bf x}^2$ then it follows from the above formula that
$$
\left[\matrix{ t'\cr  {\bf x}'}\right]= \left[\matrix{0\cr (1-P){\bf x}}\right]+ \left[\matrix{ \cosh s&-\sinh s\cr-\sinh s &\cosh s}\right]\left[\matrix{ t\cr P{\bf x}}\right]=
$$
where  $P$ is the projection operator along ${\bf v}$ with matrix elements $P_{ij}=v^iv^j/|{\bf v}^2|$. This is just taking the standard rapidity formula for an $x,t$ boost  and only altering the components of ${\bf x}$ parallel to ${\bf v}$.

Comment: Okay, fine! But how do you derive it?