# Why do Lorentz boosts not form a group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

An excerpt from my lecture notes on relativity (translated from Dutch):

"Special (special in the notes indicates that the determinant of the representation matrix equals +1) Lorentz transformations with arbitrary velocities don't form a group. Special Lorentz transformations form a group (an Abelian subgroup of the Lorentzgroup) only when the boosts are parallel."

I don't see this. Why don't arbitrary boosts in arbitrary directions form a group? What criterion (closed under the operation, existence of the inverse, containing neutral element etc) of forming a group is not satisfied here?

Comment: If by special you ean has determinant=1 then we have a group pf course, but I   think the word "special" in regard to Lorentz tranformations means a "boost."  Composing two boosts in non-parallel directions does not result in a a boost.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395036/2451

Comment: Please edit this question so that it is clear whether you are talking about boosts or Lorentz transformations with determinant +1 when you say "special Lorentz transformation". Currently it's inconsistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why don't arbitrary boosts in arbitrary directions form a group?

They don’t form a group because the composition of two non-parallel boosts is not a boost. Instead, the composition is a boost *combined with a rotation*. This rotation is known as a [Wigner rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation).

See [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/515663/special-relativity-perpendicular-boosts-equaling-to-a-rotation-after-a-boost/515690#515690) to a related question for an explicit example.

The best way to understand the origin of the Wigner rotation is by considering infinitesimal Lorentz transformations and their generators. As mentioned [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480463/combining-two-lorentz-boosts/480467#480467), the commutator of two boost generators is a rotation generator.

The “special Lorentz transformations”, which are those having a determinant equal to 1, include boosts, rotations, and compositions of these, and *do* form a group.