# Lorentz boost transformations form a group?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, group-theory, commutator, lie-algebra

In the QFT book of Ryder, he states that Lorentz boost transformations do NOT form a group. This is due to the boost generators $\textbf{K}$, i.e. they do not form a closed algebra under commutation. Mathematically:

\begin{equation}
[ K^{i}, K^{j} ]=-i{\epsilon^{ijk}}J^{k}.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
This makes sense to me since boosts cause the Lorentz group (group?) to be non-compact ( you can keep boosting the system till you reach $c$). Is that what he means?

Comment: I think the Lorentz transformations compose the restricted Lorentz group (?)

Comment: Combining two Lorentz boosts results to a rotation followed by a Lorentz boost or by a Lorentz boost  followed by a rotation, any order you like more. See the answers here [Combining two Lorentz boosts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480463/combining-two-lorentz-boosts/620784#620784)

Comment: Proper homogeneous Lorentz transformations form a 6-parametric group. What are the proper homogeneous Lorentz transformations and why they  form a group see here [Show that any proper homogeneous Lorentz transformation may be expressed as the product of a boost times a rotation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/588883/)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525974/226902

Answer (score 5):

All this means is that the *pure boosts* do not form a subgroup of the Lorentz group. That commutator tells you that it is possible to do a series of boosts which result, overall, in a spatial rotation.

The boosts plus the spatial rotations on the other hand do of course form a subgroup, specifically the restricted Lorentz group, usually denoted $SO^+(1,3)$.

It is a bit unhelpful to say "the Lorentz transformations do not form a group", since we usually think of "the Lorentz transformations" as simply being the elements of $SO^+(1,3)$.