# Can we define a group operation of pure Lorentz Boosts?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory

Can we define a group operation of pure Lorentz Boosts?

Consider the Lorentz group. By the [Wigner rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation), the composition of two pure boosts results in a non-pure boost. However, fortunately a Lorentz group element can always decomposited into a composition of a pure boost and a rotation by [polar decomposition theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0211047.pdf), i.e. for any pure boosts $B_1$ and $B_2$ there exists unique pure boost $B_3$ and unique rotation $R$ such that $B_2 \circ B_1 = R \circ B_3$.

I am wondering if we can define a group operation of pure boosts. My thought is that the group operation is defined by
$$
B_2 B_1 = B_3 \text{ where } B_2 \circ B_1 = R \circ B_3 \text{ by polar decomposition.}
$$
It is a kind of looking like a quotient space of Lorentz group modulo the rotation group, e.g. the [oriented hyperbolic space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space): $SO^+(1, n)/SO(n)$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161313/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/395036/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525974/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The multiplication rule is likely not associative.

Comment: Collinear boosts form a group.

Comment: Since this binary operation clearly has totality, an identity & inverses, if as @Prahar suspects it's not associative it only defines a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#Loops), not a group.

Comment: A coset space is not a group, however: your construction is reminiscent of the axial generators of current algebra which definitely do not close to a group, but  specify projective coordinates for the analogous coset space.

Comment: This is a strictly math question, suitable for [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3092156/362193). The subgroup H of rotations specifies a right coset Hg of the Lorentz group consisting of the left action of rotations on the group, $H\times G \to G$. So the coset space G/H is the set of such orbits and is not a group for the set of boosts. Asking it there might yield pithy answers....

Comment: If you are inclined to compute an explicit (counter)example, you could use [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/402543/66086) shortcut.